# Nested react component not rendering been stuck for hours

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, components

I'm just getting started with react and javascript development in general, i'm trying to nest a component. The Home component is rendering fine, the testComp is not showing up, very stuck pls help. Thanks!

home.component.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

import testComp from "./test.component";

export default class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm">
                <testComp />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm">
                 One of four columns
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm">
                One of four columns
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm">
                One of four columns
                </div>
            </div>   
        </div> 
    );
  }
}
```

test.component.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

export default class testComp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <p> TEST TEXT </p>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please copy & paste the code here with clear labels, code shouldn't be in a screenshot or image

Comment: Fixed, help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may seem weird at first, but you have to use a capital letter at the start of the component. Try changing to:

```
export default class TestComp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <p> TEST TEXT </p>
    );
  }
}
```

and inside home component:

`import TestComp from "./test.component";`

```
<div class="col-sm">
   <TestComp />
</div>
```

You will see the component renders. Here is a [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/bootstrap-4-react-hello-world-import-forked-c6h6e?file=/src/components/homeComp.js) of the working case. You can [read more](https://blog.pusher.com/troubleshoot-react-errors/#:%7E:text=All%20React%20component%20names%20must,letter%20compiles%20down%20to%20React.) about it

Comment: Thanks worked straight away, no wonder I couldn't work out the problem haha

Comment: Yeah hard to know about :) Please accept my answer if it helped you. Happy coding